# How to become a millionaire by selling coconuts?

Tags: lateral-thinking

A woman is buying many coconuts for 5\$ a dozen. Afterwards, she is selling the coconuts for 3\$ a dozen.

After this transaction, the woman has become a millionaire!

How could that happen?

---

Hint:

> This is a lateral thinking riddle :-) Try to become aware of your silent assumptions. List all the aspects you are assuming, and question them.

---

Source:
I found this riddle on the webpage of [Jürgen Stock](http://www.juergen-stock.de/in-10-minuten-laterales-denken-lernen-teil-i/).

However I think this riddle is widely known in the Lateral Thinking community. I share it because it hit me where I found it amazingly difficult to become aware.

Comment: Even though there is a well known intended answer, I'm voting to close as too broad as theres a lot of viable alternatives. She could have won the lottery, been donated the money, earnt it as another part of a business, there could have been a large shipping fee etc.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Yeah, I see this seems too easy and too wellknown. Ok, go on and close it; at least I've learnt something about posting puzzles.

Comment: I think the issue isn't that it's too easy, but that there are too many alternate solutions. Easy puzzles are perfectly fine! But when there are a lot of answers, and answers are open to a lot of interpretation, that means it's not a great fit for Puzzling. (We like having a single definitive answer to questions, so the site functions as an archive of good puzzles and their answers.)

Comment: @Deuvosi thank you for your explanation. In my understanding of lateral thinking puzzles, this is the very challenge. There seem to be many solutions, so I feel lost. But only one solution is perfectly matching. All the examples Beastly Gerbil has mentioned require the setting to be creatively enhanced, e.g. a lottery game was played before. The intended solution however does not require to enhance the setting itself. Rubio [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6089/71281) describes this by "When you see the right answer you _know_ it is the right answer".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

> the woman was initially a billionaire but wasted all her money and became a millionaire.

Answer (score 0):

This is a well known puzzle with a simple answer

> She was a Billionaire before

Comment: BOOM! 5 seconds!

Comment: rot13(V xabj guvf vf gur bssvpvny nafjre, ohg vg qbrfa'g ubyq hc irel jryy. Fur jbhyq unir gb fryy arneyl fvk ovyyvba pbpbahgf gb ybfr guvf zhpu zbarl guvf jnl. Vs fur pbhyq fryy 10,000 n qnl, vg jbhyq gnxr ure 1,600 lrnef. Vg frrzf sne, sne zber cynhfvoyr sbe ure gb fvzcyl unir jba gur ybggrel, be gb unir znqr gur zvyyvba guebhtu fbzr bgure aba-pbpbahg-eryngrq zrnaf.)

Comment: @plasticinsect — assume she had rot13(rknpgyl 1 ovyyvba qbyynef orsber) and then bought and sold exactly one dozen coconuts.

Comment: This requires either that "millionaire" not be a subset of "billionaire" or "continue being" be a subset of "become".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

> She became a millionaire from activities not involving coconuts?